# Sas, print unique values for many variables

Tags: sql, sas

If I have a dataset A like this:

```
a b c
1 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
3 1 2
3 2 2
```

For columns a and b I want to print the unique values in one operation (in my real dataset I have 40 columns I want to print the unique values for.

I can do it in sql with this command:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select distinct a from
A
```

But then I have to run it for every variable, which takes a lot of time. I really want to print out the unique values on this format:

```
a 1 2 3
b 1 2
```

or even better

```
a b
1 1
2 2
3 .
```

If it could be possible to put all the variable names and loop through each of them and print the unique variables, I would be very happy

Is that possible in SAS. I do not need the full solution. Only to be pointed in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is long but should give the answer you want. It puts your variables in a list then loops over them twice -- the first time to print the unique value, the second time to delete duplicates after merging:

```
data test;
    length a b c 3;
    input a b c;
    datalines;
    1 1 1
    2 1 2
    2 2 1
    3 1 2
    3 2 2
    ;
run;

** put variables into list **;
proc sql noprint;
    select NAME
    into: varlist separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
    where upcase(libname)="WORK" and upcase(memname)="TEST";
quit;

** loop over each variable **;
%macro loop_through(varlist);
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist.));;
        %let var=%scan(&varlist.,&i.);

        /* output the frequency for each variable only keeping the value */
        proc freq data = test noprint;
            table &var. / out=freq_&var.(keep=&var.);
        run;

        /* merge that output with the same dataset each iteration */
        data freq1_&var.; set freq_&var.;
            temp_var = "temp";
        run;

        data merged;
            merge freq1:;
            by temp_var;
        run;
    %end;

    /* remove duplicates after merging */
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist.));;
        %let var=%scan(&varlist.,&i.);
        data merged; set merged;
            if lag(&var.) = &var. then &var. = .;
        run;
    %end;

    /* delete individual frequency datasets */
    proc datasets nolist; delete freq:; quit;

    /* output final dataset */
    data final; set merged;
        drop temp_var;
    run;
%mend;

%loop_through(&varlist.);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks. This is the exact solution to my problem:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this will save time, but you can combine the results using `union all`:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
    select distinct 'a', a from t union all
    select distinct 'b', b from t union all
    . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you closest, in my mind.

```
data have;
input a b c;
datalines;
1 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 1
3 1 2
3 2 2
;;;;
run;
proc tabulate data=have out=want;
  class a b c;
  tables n,(a b c);
run;
```

Then transpose or whatever you like the result to get to exactly where you want.